# What Sort of Things Would a Programmer Put in the ActiveRecord::Base class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-view-controller

So I am new to rails and just started learning it today. I was wondering what sort of code a programmer would put in the ActiveRecord::Base class. I have a general idea about MVC so I want to know specifically about the Base class not about what I would generally find in the Model.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programmers who *create* Rails put [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb) into `ActiveRecord::Base`.

An average programmer who *uses* Rails (i.e. develops a Rails application) would typically not touch it.

Comment: thanks man that cleared things up a bit, would upvote but I don't have enough rep lolol

Comment: No worries, as long as things cleared up for you.